# How to troubleshoot google cloud instance issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a google VM instance that stopped working sometime in the last 4 days. The last time I tried to access it, everything was fine. By 'stopped working' I mean:

- Unable to connect to websites hosted at that instance
- Unable to connect to the instance using gcloud compute ssh

I **can** connect to the instance by opening an ssh terminal in a browser window from within console.gcloud.google.com.

Running gcloud compute ssh from my local terminal results in:

```
ssh: connect to host 34.69.41.204 port 22: Operation timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Connecting over http results in:

```
    wget http://panam.whensparksfly.org
--2021-10-11 11:18:00--  http://panam.whensparksfly.org/
Resolving panam.whensparksfly.org (panam.whensparksfly.org)... 34.69.41.204
Connecting to panam.whensparksfly.org (panam.whensparksfly.org)|34.69.41.204|:80... failed: Operation timed out.
```

If I run that same wget command from the browser-based terminal I started from https://console.gcloud.google.com, it works.

I've tried stopping and restarting the instance. I also have another instance that I usually leave off. I started that instance and had the same problem.

Here are the firewall rules for that instance:
[image: Google cloud firewall rules]

How should I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Have you allowed HTTP/HTTPS request in the firewall so that the hosted website will be available to the internet? Also, in order to connect to instances from your local machine, you should allow ssh ingress rule in the firewall.

Comment: Is the instance attached to a static ip? if not, the IP could have changed after the VM restart

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've added a screenshot of my firewall rules to my question. wget panam.whensparksfly.org from my local compute reports the IP address as 34.69.41.204, which is the same as reported in the Google Cloud console, so the IP address didn't change when I restarted it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to my specific question about how to troubleshoot the problem, but here's how I resolved the issue:

1. Create a new [machine image](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/03/google-machine-images-beta/) from the original instance
2. Create a new instance from the machine image. Go to the Machine Images page in the Google Cloud Console, click the Actions button for the desired image, then click create instance.
3. I was able to transfer my static external IP address to the new instance by following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#console_2).

Everything is now working as before.